# ValueError: arrays must all be same length - print dataframe to CSV

Tags: python, windows, pandas, csv, dataframe

thanks for stopping by!  I was hoping to get some help creating a csv using pandas dataframe.  Here is my code:

```html
a = ldamallet[bow_corpus_new[:21]]
b = data_text_new

print(a)
print("/n")
print(b)

d = {'Preprocessed Document': b['Preprocessed Document'].tolist(), 
     'topic_0': a[0][1], 
     'topic_1': a[1][1], 
     'topic_2': a[2][1], 
     'topic_3': a[3][1], 
     'topic_4': a[4][1], 
     'topic_5': a[5][1], 
     'topic_6': a[6][1], 
     'topic_7': a[7][1], 
     'topic_8': a[8][1], 
     'topic_9': a[9][1], 
     'topic_10': a[10][1],
     'topic_11': a[11][1], 
     'topic_12': a[12][1],
     'topic_13': a[13][1],
     'topic_14': a[14][1],
     'topic_15': a[15][1],
     'topic_16': a[16][1],
     'topic_17': a[17][1],
     'topic_18': a[18][1],
     'topic_19': a[19][1]}

print(d)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.to_csv("test.csv", index=False)
```

The data:

print(a): the format is in tuples

[[(topic number: 0, topic percentage),...(19, #)], [(topic distribution for next row, #)...(19, .819438),...(#,#),...]

[image: print(a)]

print(b)

[image: print(b)]

Here is my error:
[image: the error]

This is the size of the dataframe:

[image: The size of b]

[image: the shape of a]

[image: shape of a]

This is what I wished it looked like:
[image: the dream]

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I'm thinking this will be just one row of the dataframe but you `b` is the whole list. Try changing to `'Preprocessed Document': 'someword1'`.

Comment: The issue is that `a` is a list of a list of tuples

Comment: @MattCremeens Thank you for reaching out it means a lot, data_new has a column called 'Preprocessed Documents' which contains 1,048,575 rows of comments.  I would like to pass each row into the function ldamallet for topic detection so the number of rows should correlate.  I am struggling to figure out how to iterate through the entire column so I can learn which topics each row falls into.

Comment: @Chris yes a is a list of tuples - the function ldamallet outputs in this format by design it's from a library so I don't have digression over changing the format of the function.  Wish I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easiest to get the second value of each tuple for all of the rows in it's own list. Something like this

```
topic_0=[]
topic_1=[]
topic_2=[]
...and so on
for i in a:
    topic_0.append(i[0][1])
    topic_1.append(i[1][1])
    topic_2.append(i[2][1])
    ...and so on
```

Then you can make your dictionary like so

```
d = {'Preprocessed Document': b['Preprocessed Document'].tolist(), 
     'topic_0': topic_0, 
     'topic_1': topic_1, 
      etc. }
```

Answer (score 0):

I took @mattcremeens advice and it worked.  I've posted the full code below.  He was right about nixing the tuples my previous code wasn't iterating through the rows but only printed the first row.

```html
topic_0=[]
topic_1=[]
topic_2=[]
topic_3=[]
topic_4=[]
topic_5=[]
topic_6=[]
topic_7=[]
topic_8=[]
topic_9=[]
topic_10=[]
topic_11=[]
topic_12=[]
topic_13=[]
topic_14=[]
topic_15=[]
topic_16=[]
topic_17=[]
topic_18=[]
topic_19=[]


for i in a:
    topic_0.append(i[0][1])
    topic_1.append(i[1][1])
    topic_2.append(i[2][1])
    topic_3.append(i[3][1])
    topic_4.append(i[4][1])
    topic_5.append(i[5][1])
    topic_6.append(i[6][1])
    topic_7.append(i[7][1])
    topic_8.append(i[8][1])
    topic_9.append(i[9][1])
    topic_10.append(i[10][1])
    topic_11.append(i[11][1])
    topic_12.append(i[12][1])
    topic_13.append(i[13][1])
    topic_14.append(i[14][1])
    topic_15.append(i[15][1])
    topic_16.append(i[16][1])
    topic_17.append(i[17][1])
    topic_18.append(i[18][1])
    topic_19.append(i[19][1])
    
d = {'Preprocessed Document': b['Preprocessed Document'].tolist(),
     'topic_0': topic_0,
     'topic_1': topic_1,
     'topic_2': topic_2,
     'topic_3': topic_3,
     'topic_4': topic_4,
     'topic_5': topic_5,
     'topic_6': topic_6,
     'topic_7': topic_7,
     'topic_8': topic_8,
     'topic_9': topic_9,
     'topic_10': topic_10,
     'topic_11': topic_11,
     'topic_12': topic_12,
     'topic_13': topic_13,
     'topic_14': topic_14,
     'topic_15': topic_15,
     'topic_16': topic_16,
     'topic_17': topic_17,
     'topic_18': topic_18,
     'topic_19': topic_19}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.to_csv("test.csv", index=False, mode = 'a')
```